# Kotlin String to ULong

Tags: kotlin

I'm using Kotlin on Linux (kotlinc-jvm 1.7.21)

I would like to store a large number in a variable. So I found ULong to store 64 bits numbers.
My number in binary is : `1111100001111100001111100001111110001111110001111110001111110001`. This is 64 bits long, so just under the limit of a ULong variable.
However, when I try to convert it from String to ULong,

```kotlin
var myLargeNumber = "1111100001111100001111100001111110001111110001111110001111110001".toULong()
```

I have the error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid number format: '1111100001111100001111100001111110001111110001111110001111110001'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myLargeNumber.toULong()` will try to interpret the number in base 10. `1111100001111100001111100001111110001111110001111110001111110001` is a lot larger than the maximum `ULong` value of `18446744073709551615`, so `toULong()` fails

To interpret the number as a binary number you can instead [specify the radix](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-u-long.html):

```kotlin
fun main() {
  val myLargeNumber = "1111100001111100001111100001111110001111110001111110001111110001"
    .toULong(radix = 2) // treat the string as a base 2 number
  println(myLargeNumber)
  // output: 17905254523795399665
}
```